# How to get stock for configured item in cart?

Tags: php, magento

With a simple product I can do this:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$item = $quote->getItemById($params['item']); // $params['item'] contains item id
$product = $item->getProduct();
$stockQty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
```

However, if the item is a configured product, it tries to get the stock of its parent configurable product, which in most cases has an inventory of zero.

How can I get the stock quantity of a configured product, preferably without looping through its configurable parent's child products?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a variable that determines the stock status depending on the stock status of the children of the configurable product:

```
$inStock = true;
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

$item = $quote->getItemById($params['item']); // $params['item'] contains item id
$_product = $item->getProduct();
$configuredProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$children = $configuredProduct->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
foreach($children as $simpleProduct) {
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getProduct()->getId() != $simpleProduct->getId()) continue;

        $stockQty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleProduct)->getQty();
        if ($stockQty <= 0) {
            $inStock = false;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this won't work at all, different variations/children can have different stock levels, this won't help find the correct product.

Comment: Just add an extra IF condition inside the for loop to check of the child matches?

Comment: The reason I asked this question was because I was looking for a solution that didn't loop through all the children, but somehow got the simple product directly from the item id or item object.

Comment: You will always have to loop through the items if you start from your Quote.

Comment: Okay then. Can you add the conditional to your example code loop that would give me the amount of the item in question in stock?

Comment: What would that if condition be?